# generate graphs for website?

Tags: .net, iis, graph

i need to generate graphs and equations for a website.
the webserver runs on IIS and windows.

I was looking at mathplot but wasn't sure if it can be used in a web environment

.NET is preferred

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Asp.net Charting control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx)

[Download here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&DisplayLang=en)

Answer (score 0):

The Flash-based charts by [amCharts](http://amcharts.com/) are pretty nice, you'd have to write your own server-side .NET code to initialise them or use the WPF version with Silverlight.

I've also used [Dundas](http://www.dundas.com/) charts before which although I didn't particularly like they can do most things you'd ever need from a graph.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's quite what you are looking for. It doesn't do equations for example, but take a look at [Google's chart api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/).

It's certainly not as fully featured as the MS asp.net charting library that Chanan mentions.